# Utilizar os comandos CMD windows a partir do digitado

Tags: windows, cmd

Utilizo o Cmder ou o ConEmu e estou tentando configurar algum deles para obter os comandos digitados a partir do que já digitei.
Por exemplo, se eu digitar a seguinte sequência de comandos:

```
cd Sites\site1

ssh user@ip

mysql
```

E depois digitar `UP` (setinha para cima), virá o último comando digitado, no caso `mysql`, até aí tudo certo. Mas se eu digitar `ssh` e depois digitar `UP`, o comando que virá será o `mysql`, e não o `ssh user@ip`.

Meu objetivo é, como eu digitei `ssh`, quando digitar `UP` vir os últimos comandos que começam com `ssh`, como é no terminal Ubuntu.

Isso me é muito útil, pois eu uso `ssh` em vários servidores diferentes, com IP diferentes, e assim não preciso ficar decorando e redigitando todos os IPS. Às vezes preciso usar de novo um comando que user a meses atrás, e era isso que eu usava quando estava utilizando Ubuntu.